# I am getting error while uploading product, how can i fix that?

Tags: product, mysql, backend, magento-1.7.0.1

I have managed different stores in magento and different users for this also, i have managed different users for upload product for different store.

When i try to upload product from main store then there is no any error but when i try to upload via different user then this error occured.

[image]

Comment: Did that start happening after installing a module ? If yes, I suggest you disable this module and try again.

Comment: No, recently i haven't install any module and extension.

Comment: Could you post the full trace of the error page instead of a screenshot please ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism i have updated question and added full trace error page.

Comment: Did you try to reindex all the indexes ?